# Dark metallic gray tube: Is it a LEGO?

Tags: part-identification

Unfortunately, I no longer own the piece in question. But here are the specs:

1. Dark metallic grey, like Super Battle Droids.
2. Somewhere in the vicinity of 6 inches long.
3. Flat ends: not a cut or broken pice of something else.
4. Fits perfectly in a hole for basic minifig-grabbable bars.
5. Not easily bent, but can kink slightly.

If this isn't a LEGO, say so, but bring some proof please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like ['Hose, Rigid 3mm D. 16L / 12.8cm'](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=75c16#T=P) in Pearl Dark Grey. Super Battle Droids are also in Metal Blue but none of the hoses exists in this color. Also note that the linked hose also exists in other sizes too and that the exact piece you have had might have been cut.

Note that colors mentioned refer to Bricklink's color names, LEGO company's official color names are different.